# How do I clear table rows or data if the JQuery result is empty or blank?

Tags: jquery

I have this ajax code to pull through details from a php database. The user selects from a dropdown and clicks the search button and the details populate the various rows of the table however if the result is empty the table is still populated from the previous result. How do I go about clearing the table rows if there is no result to fetch?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').click(function() {
            console.log("yes");            

            var id = $('#employee_list').val();
            console.log(id);
            if (id != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("result");
                        $('#employee_details').css("display", "block");
                        $('#employee_name').text(data.name);
                        $('#employee_address').text(data.address);
                        $('#employee_gender').text(data.gender);
                        $('#employee_designation').text(data.designation);
                        $('#employee_age').text(data.age);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                alert("Please Select Employee");
                $('#employee_details').css("display", "none");
                $("#employee_details tbody tr td").html("");
            }
        });

        $('#search').click(function() {
            console.log("yes2");           

            var id = $('#employee_list').val();
            console.log(id);
            if (id != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch2.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("result2");
                        $('#employee_details').css("display", "block");
                        $('#employee_name2').text(data.name2);
                        $('#employee_address2').text(data.address2);
                        $('#employee_gender2').text(data.gender2);
                        $('#employee_designation2').text(data.designation2);
                        $('#employee_age2').text(data.age2);
                    }

                })
            } else {
                alert("Please Select Employee");
                $('#employee_details2').css("display", "none");
                $("#employee_details2 tbody tr td").html("");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not check for the returned data, and act accordingly?

Comment: Thanks Nico. That points me in the right direction .